# how to set a dynamic web module in eclipse luna 4.4?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I cannot seem to find the Project Facets in this version of eclipse,
can someone help me find what i should install or update in order to be able to make my project a dynamic web module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers package does contain this. But obviously this is only available for projects which is configured to use project facets. It is available under Project properties / Project Facets. It also appears if your project isn't configured to use project facets, in which case it will display help text and a link to convert your project.